# Scrolling to top of page on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am attempting to create some animations for when an element is scrolled into place in my [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) react application. I have tried using several react scroll packages, but am not getting the results I need because I want to apply the animation to child components that are all mapped from the same parent component (and thus, all child components animate at the same time when the first child component is scrolled into place).

To work around this, I was thinking of just getting the current scroll position and the individual positions in for each component but am quite stuck and unclear on how to do this properly. For my child component, should I just call a function when the `onScroll` event is called? Or should I instead use something like `jsx` to get the these various window positions and run some evaluations and functions when the `DOM` is updated to the proper place I want?

Thanks, any help would be appreciated! I spent a couple days now searching for answers but think I'm just more stuck on how to call different window and element events and properties and how to compare them, and don't even know if this is neccessary and if there is instead an easier solution for scrolling animations, ideally, in just plain [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs), without any packages.

Comment: Does react-waypoint not help?

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, I just took a look and you're right, I think it will do what I need!

Comment: You can simply use `window.scrollTop(0)`

Answer (score 1):

Easy! Just do it with the scrollTop method on DOM ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

You can also just do it like this:

```
$(document).scrollTop(0);
```